# My case-statement methode prints a sentence twice in c

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am trying to work with a switch-statement. But it doenst really work for me, because if I run it, it prints the sentence ''task 1 = A, task 2 = B, task = C\n'' twice after I choose A, B or C. Why is this/ What do I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int b;
     while (b)
     {
     char a;
  printf("task 1 = A, task 2 = B, task = C\n");
  scanf("%c", &a);


  switch ( a )
  {

     case 'A':
         printf("task 1\n");

     break;

     case 'B':
          printf("task 2\n");

     break;


     case 'C':
           printf("task 3\n");
     break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: To start with you have *undefined behavior* in your program. What is the value of variable `b`? You don't know, and neither do anyone else. Uninitialized local variables have indeterminate values, and using them uninitialized leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

On next iteration `scanf` read the `\n` character left behind by previous `scanf` in input buffer. A space before `%c` is able to consume any number of white-spaces.
Try this

```
scanf(" %c", &a);
       ^ Place a space before `%c
```

Another thing is that you have not initialized `b`. Your program invokes undefined behavior.